# The kinds of rendering in dynatrace~~

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, profiling

I use Dynatrace to find problems in my company site. I want to say,wow, this is a beautiful tool for page performance.

But I found there are many kinds of rendering in dynatrace. For example:

1. Calculating generic layout
2. Calculating flow layout
3. Scheduling layout task

What's the difference between these?

Comment: please add the tags "java" and "performance" to this posting. also please refine your question.

Answer (score 2):

Dynatrace have a good article called [understanding internet explorer rendering behaviour](https://web.archive.org/web/20121120093321/http://blog.dynatrace.com:80/2009/12/12/understanding-internet-explorer-rendering-behaviour/). It also references a Gecko/Firefox link that is worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

for rendering analysis in dynatrace you should also check out the dynatrace free trial. We moved the capabilities from AJAX Edition to Dynatrace Browser Diagnostics++. What makes rendering activities easier to analyze is that we are now also capturing screenshots everytime something significantly changes.

I wrote a little blog about this that you may find helpful: http://apmblog.compuware.com/2014/12/11/dynatrace-ajax-edition-4-5-last-page-chapter-yet-story-continues/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for reference. Answers should be self-contained.